# R: How to repeat a sequence such that its length is equal to a user defined number?

Tags: r

Please note that this question is not a duplicate.

I am trying to repeat this sequence `4, 2` such that if a user defined its length to be 3, then the outcome will be `4,2,4`.

If user defines length to be 5, then outcome will be `4,2,4,2,4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rep` with parameter `length.out`:

```
rep(c(4, 2), length.out = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function may be modifiable for more things for you. 
Creates string that is at most 1 more than what you need for the repeat. Then prints the requested (n)

```
seq_select<- function(n) {
  string<-rep(c(4,2),round(n/2))
  print(string[1:n])
} 

> seq_select(3)
[1] 4 2 4
```